# AspNetUsers replace Id from string to int - cannot insert NULL into Column 'Id' Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I need to change the key column `Id` in `AspNetUsers` from string to int.

I followed this guide :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

I did everything in this guide except the `start-up.Auth` configuration (I only have
`app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());`)

When trying to register a user, I'm getting this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'click2lockdb.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls

I tried to add the Id manually :

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]  
public override int Id { get; set; }
```

but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't arbitrarily change the way that the Identity framework works. Where will the database get its autogenerated number? Is the column set to be an identity column and auto incremented? There's an abstraction that handles all of this for you, and you can't change it.

Comment: I followed Microsoft guide that explains how to do it, 
but it looks like i missed something, I changed type of the column Id, which is an identity column

Comment: It's not that simple. There are other tables with foreign key constraints to that table.